# Show/Hide data from Barchart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart with `Chart.js` where one can show and hide the bars (Persons). I know that it is possible to click the labels on the legend to do so, but since all data has the same legend, all bars get hidden. And if I use multiple datasets, the bars are all shown together in one bar (not sure how to explain this correctly).

Here's an [example](https://jsbin.com/lesowozuji/edit?html,js,output) of what I currently have:

```
var options = {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
     labels: ['Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Person 3', 'Person 4'],
     datasets: [{
       label: 'Days',
       data: [20, 42, 51, 4],
       backgroundColor: ['#FFC857', '#E9724C', '#C5283D', '#481D24']
     }]
   },
   options: {
     scales: {
       xAxes: [{
         time: {
           unit: 'day'
         },
       }],

     },
     legend: {
       display: true
     },
     responsive: true
   }
 }
var ctx = document.getElementById("calendarStats").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

It would be great if someone could help me out here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you want seperate legends for each person?

Comment: Yes, if that's somehow possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```js
 var options = {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
    
     datasets: [{
       label: 'Person 1',
       data: [20],
       backgroundColor: ['#FFC857']
     }, {
       label: 'Person 2',
       data: [42],
       backgroundColor: ['#E9724C']
     },{
       label: 'Person 3',
       data: [51],
       backgroundColor: ['#C5283D']
     },{
       label: 'Person 4',
       data: [4],
       backgroundColor: ['#481D24']
     }]
   },
   options: {
     scales: {
       xAxes: [{
         time: {
           unit: 'day'
         },
       }],

     },
     legend: {
       display: true
     },
     responsive: true
   }
 }
var ctx = document.getElementById("calendarStats").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="calendarStats"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```